# How to trigger the final NERO encounter?

Tags: days-gone

I've finished the game, and am driving around waiting for the final NERO encounter to trigger.  I've seen walkthroughs of the gameplay where they say "drive around for a while until it triggers", however, was wondering if there is actually a location or something else which will trigger it sooner than waiting for a random event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the final encounter is triggered by *time*, not by a location.  I went to Lost Lake camp, slept a few times and the call from O'Brien came in to start the final NERO encounter.